# Trouble with SELECT CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I want to get some data from my database for the past 31 days. When column 'finalized' is NULL I want to get data from column 'today', but if column 'finalized' isn't NULL I want to get data from column 'finalized'. I always want to get the last entered row.

TABLE MyEarnings

```
id          INT(11) AI
date        datetime
today       decimal(4,2)    NULL
finalized   decimal(4,2)    NULL

id    date                   today    finalized
-----------------------------------------------
6     2016-02-04 04:52:00    0.39     NULL
5     2016-02-03 12:34:00    NULL     19.74
4     2016-02-03 12:33:00    15.96    NULL
3     2016-02-03 12:32:00    12.32    NULL
2     2016-02-02 15:16:00    NULL     9.16
1     2016-02-02 14:29:00    2.20     NULL
```

SQL

```
SELECT
    date,
    CASE
        WHEN finalized=NULL
            THEN today
        WHEN finalized!=NULL
            THEN finalized
        END
    AS earn
FROM MyEarnings
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY date  ASC
LIMIT 0 , 31
```

This is what I end up with

```
date                   earn
---------------------------
2016-02-02 00:00:00    NULL
2016-02-03 00:00:00    NULL
2016-02-04 00:00:00    NULL
```

What I'm looking to get

```
date                   earn
----------------------------
2016-02-02 00:00:00    9.16
2016-02-03 00:00:00    19.74
2016-02-04 00:00:00    0.39
```

## EDIT

I also want to get a summary for each month of all values in 'finalized'-column with the max 'id' for each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation, but it is a bit tricky. I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
       COALESCE(MAX(finalized), MAX(today)) as earn
FROM MyEarnings
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY date  ASC
LIMIT 0 , 31;
```

This returns the maximum value of `today`.  You may want the most recent value.  If so, the simplest method is probably the `GROUP_CONCAT()`/`SUBSTRING_INDEX()` method:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
       COALESCE(MAX(finalized),
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(today ORDER BY date DESC), ',', 1) + 0
               ) as earn
FROM MyEarnings
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY date  ASC
LIMIT 0 , 31;
```

It is a bit yucky to convert numbers to strings and back for this purpose.  Alternative methods require additional joins or using variables.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not always the MAX-value I want, as when my earnings are finalized it could be lowered. So I need the row with the highest 'id'.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking to do! Thank you!

Comment: A question, will your last code give me the MAX finalized no regards to if there was a lower value in 'finalized' added with a later date? I want both the 'today'-column and 'finalized'-column to get me the value with the highest ID.

Comment: I also want to get a summary for each month of all values in 'finalized'-column with the max 'id' for each day.

Comment: @DavidHermansson . . . The sample data has only one value of `finalized` on each day.  If this is available, the query returns this value; otherwise, it returns the most recent value for `today`.

Answer (score 2):

use `CASE` `WHEN` like this:

```
CASE
        WHEN finalized IS NULL
            THEN today
        ELSE finalized
        END
AS earn
```

Replace query:

```
SELECT date, (CASE
                  WHEN finalized IS NULL THEN today
                  ELSE finalized
              END;    
) AS earn
FROM MyEarnings
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 0,31
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare null with !=, you should use is null and is not null like this:

```
SELECT
date,
CASE
    WHEN finalized is null THEN today
    ELSE finalized
    END AS earn
FROM MyEarnings
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY date  ASC  LIMIT 0 , 31
```

Also, if your first condition is when its null, you don't need to check if its not null , ELSE will be enough since the opposite of null is not null

Answer (score 0):

Using greatest id to determine last row added (cons: stretching traditional use of id):

```
SELECT DATE(me.date) date,
       COALESCE(me.finalized,me.today) earn
  FROM MyEarnings me 
  JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) max_id
      FROM MyEarnings
  GROUP BY DATE(date)
  ORDER BY DATE(date)
     LIMIT 31 
      ) o
    ON o.max_id = me.id
```

Using greatest date to determine last row added (cons: possible dupes):

```
SELECT DATE(me.date) date,
       COALESCE(me.finalized,me.today) earn
  FROM MyEarnings me 
  JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(date) max_date
      FROM MyEarnings
  GROUP BY DATE(date)
  ORDER BY DATE(date)
     LIMIT 31 
      ) o
    ON o.max_date = me.date
```